# Is there a way to select pyqt window/ui on mouse hover?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a little problem, I am using PyQt to make UI in Maya. Problem is that my current UI has hotkeys, but unless you click on the window, you can't use it because the window of UI is not selected(running on the back when you are doing things in Maya). UI being active all the time is also inconvenient because some hotkeys are the same as Maya's. So I was wondering is there any way to select a window without clicking on it, just mouse hover. Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't suggest such behavior, as it doesn't seem very intuitive. What if the user moves the mouse inadvertently above your window, but they just wanted to move it away from its current position? Note that if you're using a `keyPressEvent` override to handle shortcuts that might not be the proper choice, and you should instead use QActions with proper QShortcuts set for them: QShortcuts have a [`context()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html#context-prop) property that allows them to be available even when their related widget is visible but not in an active window (`ApplicationShortcut`).

Comment: QShortcuts works amazing, thanks!